# Qmake and Make in wrong directories?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

EDIT: Okay, so instead of just doing `qmake sample.pro` , I specified the directory of qmake and did `/Users/***/Qt5.4.1/5.4/clang_64/bin/qmake sample.pro` and I think it worked. But when I do `make` , it still doesn't work.

---

I'm on OSX
When I do `qmake -v`, I get:

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.7.4 in /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib
```

This directory doesn't even exist it seems...and I'm using QT 5.4.1
When I do `which qmake`, I get:

```
/Users/***/anaconda/bin/qmake
```

This DOES exist, but it's not the qmake that comes in the QT installed folder. The qmake that is included in the installed QT folder is:

```
/Users/***/Qt5.4.1/5.4/clang_64/bin/qmake
```

So I have a folder with my project in it and I do run qmake on QT Creator, I get a make file in the folder, so I tried `make` in terminal and I get:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile v2.pro
make: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile] Error 1
```

This directory indeed doesn't exist...

When I do `$PATH` :

`-bash:   /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/***/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set path to `qmake` in Creator.

https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-qmake.html